# find_if error: no viable conversion from iterators

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ program and I'm trying to use the find_if function.

Here is what I have:

[image]

And here is the error I get:

[image]

My understanding is that the iterator returned by find_if is not the same as what I'm declaring. However, I read the C++ documentation for find_if [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) and according to this, I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: You probably need to use `const_iterator` since your `data` param is passed by const reference. But even better, use `auto`.

Comment: Although your error appears to be evident based on the shown screenshot, you need to properly format your question as plain text. If you look around on stackoverflow.com, all well-prepared questions show their code as plain text, and you have not explained why your question deserves an exception to this rule. Poorly-formatted questions should not be rewarded with an answer. In addition to formatting your question as plain text, your question must meet all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `data` is a `const vector<CDCRecord>&`, meaning that when you call `data.begin()` and `data.end()`, you're getting back `vector<CDCRecord>::const_iterator`s rather than `vector<CDCRecord>::iterator`s. As a result, when you try assigning the result of `find_if` to a regular old `iterator`, it's a type error because the return type is a `const_iterator`.

To fix this, either explicitly change the type of the iterator `it` to be a `const_iterator`, or just use `auto` and have the compiler figure it out for you.